# Distinct edge weight assumption in MST algorithms

Tags: algorithms, graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

My lecture notes for minimum spanning trees say that:

> A graph can have several minimum spanning trees but if the edge weights are distinct then the minimum spanning tree is unique. Without loss of generality, we can
> assume that the edge weights are distinct

I'm trying to convince myself that the distinct edge weights assumption in MST algorithms is a valid one but haven't made much progress. I thought about maybe considering the smallest absolute difference between two adjacent edge weights (call this $\delta$) and then let $\alpha = \delta / m$ where $m$ is the number of edges. If there's $k$ edges of the same weight $w$, order them arbitrarily and replace the edge weight by $w + i\times\alpha$ for $0\le i<k$. Then all edge weights are unique and any MST algorithm applied for these new weights should give a valid MST for the original weights. I'm not convinced that this works though.

Comment: What do you mean ? What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. A bit more work is needed.

---

Suppose we have developed a comparison-based MST algorithm $\mathcal A$ for graphs of distinct edge-weights. (You will probably not see an MST algorithm that is not comparison-based.)

Let $G=(E,V,w)$ be a weighted graph where edge-weights might have duplicates. How can we obtain an MST of $G$ using $\mathcal A$?

We can run $\mathcal A$ on $G$, breaking ties among the same edge-weights arbitrarily and consistently, to obtain a spanning tree $T$. However, is $T$ an MST of $G$ still? That is your question.

Let we sort all edge-weights (with duplicates) according to the same tie breaking rules when we ran $\mathcal A$ to obtain $T$. Suppose we get $e_1, \cdots, e_m$. Let $\delta_E$ be the smallest nonzero absolute difference between two edge-weights. Let $\delta_G$ be the smallest nonzero absolute difference between the weights of two spanning trees of $G$. If all edge-weights are the same or all weights of spanning trees are the same, $T$ is trivially an MST. Assume otherwise, so both $\delta_E$ and $\delta_G$ are well-defined. Let $G^+=(V, E, w^+)$, where $$w^+(e_i)=w(e_i)+\frac{i\min(\delta_E, \delta_G)}{n^2}.$$ Then
$$i<j\iff w^+(e_i)<w^+(e_j).$$
In particular, all edge-weights of $G^+$ are distinct.

Now we run $\mathcal A$ on $G^+$. Since the comparison order of all edges for $G$ is the same as that of $G^+$, the same spanning tree $T$ will be obtained. Since $\mathcal A$ is an MST algorithm, $w^+(T)\le w^+(T')$ for any spanning tree $T'$ of $G^+$ (or of $G$, since the spanning trees of $G$ are the same as the spanning trees of $G^+$).

$$w(T)<w^+(T)\le w^+(T')\le w(T')+(n-1)\frac{n\delta_G}{n^2}<w(T')+ \delta_G$$

By the definition of $\delta_G$, this means $w(T)<w(T')$.

Comment: Another way to convince yourself is to follow the proof of each MST algorithm, checking that it is valid for graphs with possible equal edge-weights. It does not prove for all comparison-based MST algorithms, of course.

Comment: would this argument hold if the algorithm is for a second-best MST instead? this problem has a convenient LCA-based solution that rests on the assumption that the second-best MST is always one edge different from the MST which in turn hinges on the assumption of distinct edge weights. since i'm unable to find answers, can you justify a bit how this could also work without distinct edge weights? https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/second_best_mst.html https://viterbi-web.usc.edu/~shanghua/teaching/Spring2010/public_html/files/HW2_Solutions_A.pdf

Comment: for a second-best MST, read my self-answer at "Distinct edge weights assumption in second best MST algorithms only updating an edge in MST"

Answer (score 1):

The real question is: if we assign arbitrary priorities to edges of equal weights, can that break an MST algorithm ? Though this can lead to different MST's, neither the tree-ness property, nor the spanning property nor the minimum weight will be invalidated.

Assigning priorities can be done

- a priori, for instance by numbering the nodes and using the lexicographocal ordering based on (weight, number);
- a posteriori, by declaring that the edges effectively chosen during the resolution had a higher priority.